# Cross Domain Silverlight Problem with localhost

Tags: silverlight

I am currently looking into developing a silverlight app. I want to develop the app on my local machine for ease of development. I am using Apache Server on Windows which is hosting php. I am doing a WebClient DownloadStringASync to http://localhost/getData.php but the Silverlight webpage is running in visual studio asp server at http://localhost:54994/MySilverlight.aspx. I think because the silverlight app is running from the vs2010 server and I am making a call to my standard apache server it is having a cross domain problem. When the app is run the innerexception says System.Security.SecurityException at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse.

I have tried putting accesspolicy.xml file in the root of the asp server and the apache server but it still isn't fixing the problem. I know its not a problem with the code as if I run it from my website server and call the webclient request to the same domain it works fine.

Any help you can provide would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem. I needed to have to crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml with the same code. For some reason if I only have one or the other it keeps on bringing up the security exception. As soon as both files in the root of the localhost directory of apache (i.e. in the root of htdocs) the silverlight app works fine