# silverlight client fails to communicate with wcf

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, wcf, basichttpbinding

I have the weirdest problem. I have a silverlight client that uses a wcf service to get its data.
here is the code in the client:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 2147483647;
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://www.xxx.xom/SilverlightStatsService.svc");
var client = new SilverlightStatsServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);
```

These exact settings work just fine in a simple Console application but fail to work in the silverlight client...

Any ideas?

Comment: Please have a look at these:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466962/cross-domain-silverlight-problem-with-localhost][1]
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517/silverlight-cross-domain-policies][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466962/cross-domain-silverlight-problem-with-localhost
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517/silverlight-cross-domain-policies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that your web service might be missing a [clientaccesspolicy.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) file.

Comment: using fiddler it seems that the silverlight client is trying to look for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and the croosdomain.xml file on the local host... no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and see what the response from the server is.

Comment: using fiddler it seems that the silverlight client is trying to look for the clientaccesspolicy.xml file and the croosdomain.xml file on the local host... no idea why...

Comment: It should do this if the domain the .XAP file came from and the domain of the RIA service are different - it is a security thing.

Comment: Yes but it shouldn't be trying to get the clientaccesspolicy.xml from localhost unless it's trying to request data from localhost, so the question would be why it's requesting from localhost instead of what was specified in the endpoint address.

Comment: Maybe I am not reading the fiddler output right... the address is http://www.itrading.co.il/App

Comment: Some more information. If I run the test website in debug mode the silverlight client succeeds in accessing the webservive on www.itrading.co.il/App... thets so weird...